# Add style top to ID Element of other height Element by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have get `HeaderHeight` of ID element `header_top`

And add style top to ID element `menu_fix` but my JavaScript not working.

Give me checking my JavaScript is work. Thanks

```js
var HeaderHeight = document.getElementById('header_top').clientHeight;
document.getElementById("menu_fix").style.top = '"' + HeaderHeight + '"';
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
#header_top {
background: red;
padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#menu_fix {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
background: blue;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header_top">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum
</div>
<div class="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum</p>
</div>
<div id="menu_fix">

</div>
```

Comment: The code snippet doesn't show any sign of errors though.

Comment: i want add style: `top = height of header_top` but my js not add style to id `menu_fix`

Comment: @DinhCode Try it like this `("menu_fix").style.top = HeaderHeight + "px";` Also not sure why you have added `jQuery` when your using vanilla

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen is woking. Thanks for support

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this work you need to change this line:

```
document.getElementById("menu_fix").style.top = '"' + HeaderHeight + '"';
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("menu_fix").style.top = HeaderHeight + 'px';
```

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hdcon056/1/

Comment: This is woking. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

You are already pulling jquery, so this would work well

```
$('#menu_fix').css({top: $('#header_top').outerHeight()});
```